# Is it possible to trigger another Actions on Google app from within my own AoG app's fulfillment?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

This question pertains specifically to Actions on Google Apps and is concerning the ability to trigger an event/action to cause the Assistant to choose another AoG app for the end user; specifically to trigger someone else's AoG app, not one that you have written.

> **Idea:** I want to create a custom AoG app. Something like *planning-for-a-hike app*. I want my user to be able to ask about the weather. At that point, I want to pass the flow over to an already existing app to get the weather. ie. while using my app the user says *"Okay, sounds good. So what's the weather looks like today?"* and at that point I want to trigger the default weather app by passing a specific phrase back to the assistant or writing an intent.

I'm familiar with the concept of Dialogflow followup event sent back from fulfillment but am pretty sure I could not use such an intent to trigger an entire app that I didn't write. Intents exist within apps as I understand them. It is the `Google Assistant` that decides which app to trigger and appears to me that it doesn't have an API exposing that functionality.

If such a thing is possible, how would it look?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I'm not seeing how this is a duplicate question. That past post is regarding Android Apps. This question is specifically for Google Home Apps regarding triggering an app via a followup event sent from fulfillment in a webhook.

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? The marked duplicate question is not relevant in any way to this one.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoking AoG apps can only done by Google but you might be able to trigger any intent with an event from a different Dialogflow agent from your webhook by making either a :

GET request from your webhook like:

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&e=event_name&timezone=Europe/Paris&lang=en&sessionId=1234567890"
```

or a POST request to it with the headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
```

and the request body like:

```
"event":{  
  "name":"<EVENT_NAME>",
  "data":{
      “<PARAMETER_NAME>”:”<PARAMETER_VALUE>”  
  },
  "timezone":"America/New_York",
  "lang":"en",
  "sessionId":"1321321"
}
```

**Note** that you need to have access to the other agent's **Dialogflow access token**

Comment: Thanks. I think you confirmed what I suspected. Without that access token (which I'm not going to have for stock apps) I'm not going to be able to call someone else's app from within my own.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted