# How to Invoke a dialog flow agent from your google dialog flow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to connect two google dialog flow agents, so that under certain circumstances the first agent (the one active to which the user is talking to) invokes and activates a second agent which can take care of the particular situation and can talk to the user giving him the right information.

For example:

user: ok google, talk to agent 1

google agent 1: hello from agent 1

...

user: ok google now introduce me to the history of Brazil

google agent 1: to better understanding the history of Brazil I redirect you to agent 2.

google agent 2: welcome to agent 2, I will teach you everything about Brazil history

Is it possible?

Comment: What would you gain from doing this? Dialogflow agents allow 2000 intents per agent (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/quotas), so for most use cases you should be able to accomplish your goals with just one agent.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48729786/109663

Comment: @MaxWiederholt I want to mantain the two agents separate (they develop 2 different features and will be in charge of different development teams).

Comment: @techpeace great post but in that way agent1 keeps controlling the conversation while I'd like to give all conversation control to agent2.

Comment: @Manuela As mentioned in that post, only Google can invoke an action. It can't be invoked directly by another action.

Comment: @techpeace thank you, this can be a problem for my project. I hope to find some workaround to it. :)